# Simpler way to display mathematical model?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am developing a mathematical model for the power usage (watts) of a computer device against its percentage of CPU load.

So far I have:

```
P(x) when x <= 25% = 8.5 + x*0.46
P(x) when 25% > x <= 50% = 20 + x*0.08
P(x) when 50% > x < 75% = 24 + x*0.01
P(x) when x >= 75% = 25 + x*0.03
```

Where P is power usage and X is processor load

However I am not sure if there is perhaps a better way to write this out? I am pretty new to this so am really not sure and looking for some help!

Comment: This is completely unrelated to model theory, just so you know. And I'm not sure how this is even a question about mathematics.

Comment: @tomasz thank you, i guess my question really is if there is a better way to display the above mathematically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write
$$P(x) = \begin{cases} 8.5 + 0.46x & \text{if $x \leq 0.25$} \\ 
                       20 + 0.08x  & \text{if $0.25 < x \leq 0.5$} \\ 
                       24 + 0.01x  & \text{if $0.5 < x \leq 0.75$} \\
                       25 + 0.03x  & \text{if $x < 0.75$.}                      
\end{cases}$$
(I.e., display like this; fix the inequalities; and avoid percentages; I'm not sure if I should have multiplied or divided something by 100).

As an aside, I can't help noticing that your function is discontinuous; that seems weird.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that a pseudo-code (in whichever language you prefer) will be the most appropriate. What I mean here is some IF THEN / ELSE IF / ELSE IF / ENDIF. In my personal opinion, it is much more legible.